# Why are my dictionary values changing after the loop?

Tags: python, dictionary

Following is my python code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = {"Manoj":{"India":{"Airtel":2000,"Vodafone":5000},"Pakistan":{"Airtel":3000}},
    "Shafiq":{"Pakistan":{"Airtel":5000,"BP":10000}},
    "Shams":{"India":{"BP":400}},
    "Govind":{"India":{"Airtel":3000,"Vodafone":2000}},
    "Zakir":{"SriLanka":{"Etisalat":7000}}
    }

print("Printing data:")
print(data)
sumOperator={}
countryCustomers = defaultdict(list)

sum=0

for name,value in data.items():
    for country,value2 in value.items():
        countryCustomers[country].append(name)
        if country not in sumOperator:
            sumOperator[country]=value2
        else:
            for operator,value3 in value2.items():
                if operator not in sumOperator[country]:
                    sumOperator[country][operator] = value3
                else:
                    sum = sumOperator[country][operator] + value3
                    sumOperator[country][operator] = sum

print("")
print("Printing sumOperator:")
print(sumOperator)
print("")
print("Priniting data:")
print(data)

Output:
Printing data:
{'Zakir': {'SriLanka': {'Etisalat': 7000}}, 'Manoj': {'Pakistan': {'Airtel':3000}, 'India': {'Vodafone': 5000, 'Airtel': 2000}}, 'Shams': {'India': {'BP': 400}}, 'Shafiq': {'Pakistan': {'BP': 10000, 'Airtel': 5000}}, 'Govind': {'India': {'Vodafone': 2000, 'Airtel': 3000}}}

Printing sumOperator:
{'Pakistan': {'BP': 10000, 'Airtel': 8000}, 'SriLanka': {'Etisalat': 7000}, 'India': {'Vodafone': 7000, 'BP': 400, 'Airtel': 5000}}

Priniting data:
{'Zakir': {'SriLanka': {'Etisalat': 7000}}, 'Manoj': {'Pakistan': {'BP': 10000, 'Airtel': 8000}, 'India': {'Vodafone': 7000, 'BP': 400, 'Airtel': 5000}}, 'Shams': {'India': {'BP': 400}}, 'Shafiq': {'Pakistan': {'BP': 10000, 'Airtel': 5000}}, 'Govind': {'India': {'Vodafone': 2000, 'Airtel': 3000}}}
```

Why is my dictionary "data" changing values after initializing another dictionary? The last print data statement produces another data dictionary, it is not the same as the one initialized in the beginning

Comment: @Manjo seems like a [deep copy issue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) to me

Comment: [Assignment statements in Python do not copy objects, they create bindings between a target and an object. For collections that are mutable or contain mutable items, a copy is sometimes needed so one can change one copy without changing the other.](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/copy.html)

Answer (score 2):

The problem happens when your program adds values to the *sumOperator* dictionary, and mainly with the final `else` statement in your loop. You are trying to build this dictionary from the values of another dictionary, so you have `sumOperator[key] = value`, where `value` refers to an item in the other dictionary. This simply points one dictionary to the values of another; the underlying value isn't copied. Thus, when you update the values of *sumOperator*, the main *data* dictionary also got updated. To fix this, simply copy the values as you add them to the new dictionary.

The following code works, we simply add `copy()` whenever we update *sumOperator*:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from copy import copy
data = {"Manoj":{"India":{"Airtel":2000,"Vodafone":5000},"Pakistan":{"Airtel":3000}},
        "Shafiq":{"Pakistan":{"Airtel":5000,"BP":10000}},
        "Shams":{"India":{"BP":400}},
        "Govind":{"India":{"Airtel":3000,"Vodafone":2000}},
        "Zakir":{"SriLanka":{"Etisalat":7000}}
        }

print("Printing data:")
print(data)

sumOperator={}
countryCustomers = defaultdict(list)

sum=0

for name,value in data.items():
    for country,value2 in value.items():
        countryCustomers[country].append(name)
        if country not in sumOperator:
            sumOperator[country] = copy(value2)
        else:
            for operator,value3 in value2.items():
                if operator not in sumOperator[country]:
                    sumOperator[country][operator] = copy(value3)
                else:
                    sum = sumOperator[country][operator] + copy(value3)
                    sumOperator[country][operator] = sum


print("Printing sumOperator:")
print(sumOperator)

print("Priniting data:")
print(data)
```

As others have pointed out, you may wish to view the Python doc pages on [assignment statements and copying](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/copy.html). It is important to keep in mind of when you need to create an explicit copy if you do not wish to modify the original.