# Why are my dictionary's key values strings when serializing?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am collecting some data into a Python dictionary and storing it into a `.json` file. They keys are integers and the values are lists.

Here is the code:

```py
n_chapter_range = {} # {int: [int, int]}
range_start = 1
range_end = -1
for chapter in range(1, 115): 
    chapter_api_link = '' # Removed for privacy

    chapter_api = requests.get(chapter_api_link)
    chapter_json = chapter_api.json()
    
    n_verses = len(chapter_json['result'])
    range_end = n_verses + range_start - 1
    print(type(chapter)) # Confirmed as int
    n_chapter_range[int(chapter)] = [range_start, range_end] # Typecasting just in case

    range_start = range_end + 1
```

In the code `chapter` is an int. I verified by checking its type. I still try to type cast it and I expected the .json file to have integer key values, but here's a snippet of the first few entries in the file:

`{"1": [1, 7], "2": [8, 293], "3": [294, 493], "4": [494, 669], ...`

The keys are still strings.

What am I doing wrong?

I checked online if dictionary key values can be integers in Python and [this SE post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44814719/can-both-the-values-and-keys-of-a-dictionary-be-integers) confirms that they can be.

I wrote some dummy code just to confirm this:

```py
import json

foo = {
    1: 2,
    3: 4, 
    5: 7
}

with open('foo.json', 'w') as fp1:
    json.dump(foo, fp1)
```

But again, when I check `foo.json`, I get:
`{"1": 2, "3": 4, "5": 7}`

How can I make sure that the key values are integers?

I found [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29329910/why-are-my-dictionary-values-changing-after-the-loop) which I thought was similar to mine but it turned out not to be.

Comment: I know I might be able to apply a map on the keys of this dictionary but I am wondering why I should do that when this should work.

Comment: JSON keys are strings. That's a fundamental part of the JSON spec. It's based on *Javascript object notation*, hence the name, and Javascript object property names are strings.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Python, that's just how JSON works.

Comment: Is it that you want to convert the json back into objects and work with those?

Comment: Dictionary keys can be integers.  JSON keys cannot.

Answer (score -3):

There is the designed purpose and behavior or JSON:

JSON uses human readable text to store to store and transmit data objects consisting of attribute–value pairs. [Source](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)

Comment: Relevant source: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259.txt